# Using CLAMP_TO_EDGE not working correctly when using GL_LINEAR in GLSL

Tags: opengl, textures, opengl-3, texture2d

I am trying to draw textures using OpenGL/GLSL, and textures may be resized to a much bigger size than the original. When I'm using the following code for creating textures:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, width, height, 0, imageDepth, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

I receive the following result:

[image]

So... I try to improve the result by changing GL_NEAREST to GL_LINEAR:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, width, height, 0, imageDepth, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

And then I get the following result:

[image]

As you can see the results are much better, but there are those annoying border artifacts (Marked in red circles). I tried GL_CLAMP, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER but the results are always the same.
Is there something I am missing or it's just the way it is?

The draw itself is preformed by:

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertex_buffer[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(textureVerticesCoordinates), textureVerticesCoordinates, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint)0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE, 0, 0);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertex_buffer[2]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(textureImageCoordinates), textureImageCoordinates, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint)1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE, 0, 0);

glBindVertexArray(1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_index);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

**textureVerticesCoordinates** is a buffer of coordinates in the drawing space.
**textureImageCoordinates** is a buffer of texture coordinates (0.0 = topLeft, 1.1 = bottomRight)

Comment: Do you use blending or do you use a mask image?

Comment: Can you also show how you render the quad with the texture on it? Which texture coordinates do you use?

Comment: Rabbid - Blending glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA). BDL - Updated in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You are likely using a texture atlas. In order to use bilinear filtering, you'll need to provide a bit more spacing between the various sprites that have been packed into the atlas.

Comment: Can you please explain what "Texture Atlas" is? I don't think I'm using it, without even knowing what it is.

Comment: If you are texturing a marble floor, then your texture likely contains only one image: an image of marble.  If you are texturing a UI (like you are) then your texture is likely composed of multiple pieces, like a circle, some text, etc.  Thus it is an atlas.  Your texture coordinates are chosen such that each of these pieces are basically scissored out.  If you have linear filtering enabled then the GPU might be filtering from outside the boundary of each scissored piece, causing halo artifacts as seen in your screenshot.